# How to convert day of the year into a date in hive

Tags: sql, date, hive

Environment: Hive query

How can I convert yyyyddd (ddd=day of the year) with hive query into yyyy-mm-dd ?

Regards,

Answer (score 2):

you can convert it like below

```
hive> select from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('2017032','yyyyddd'),'yyyy-MM-dd');

OK
2017-02-01
```

Comment: @Belal could you please accept it by clicking on tick sign

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with string manipulation functions.  I don't have Hive on hand, but something like this:

```
date_add(concat(substr(yyyyddd, 1, 4), '-01-01'),
         cast(substr(yyyyddd, 5, 3) as int) - 1
        )
```